# Pandas update row of a group matching multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

new to pandas and first question on stakeoverflow (bare with me) :  I have a df of individuals, sometimes regrouped under a family ID. The data of interest here is  Gender and Status within the family as follows :

| RowID | FamilyID | Status | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fam_1 | head | undetermined |
| 2 | Fam_1 | wife | female |
| 3 | Fam_1 | child | undetermined |
| 4 | Fam_1 | child | male |
| 5 |  | head | male |
| 6 | Fam_2 | head | female |
| 7 | Fam_2 | child | female |
| 8 | Fam_3 | head | undetermined |
| 9 | Fam_3 | wife | female |
| 10 | Fam_3 | child | male |
| 11 | Fam_3 | head | undetermined |

Note: see row5 : some individuals are singles (no FamilyID), see Fam_3: some families have several heads (related adults).

Initially, I would need to create a new column Gender_Inferred where Gender_Inferred = male only for the heads of undetermined gender (row1) of families having a wife (in Status) and only one head (Fam_3 excluded because of row11).

I am able to create a mask for families with a wife as follows :

```
mask1 = df.groupby('FamilyID')['Status'].transform(lambda r: r.eq('wife').any())
```

a mask for the combined criteria head/undetermined to update:

```
mask2 = (df['Status'] == 'self') & (df['Gender'] == 'undeterminded')
```

I am then applying conditions with :

```
df['Gender_Inferred'] = np.nan

df['Gender_Inferred'] = np.where(mask1 & mask2, 'male', df['Gender'])
```

But I have not been able to create a mask3 for the condition 'Family has only 1 Status=head and Gender=undetermined'. It is 'almost' as if one wanted to do

```
df.groupby('FamilyID')[['006_File1_Relation','004_File1_Gender']].transform(lambda r: (r[0].eq('self') & r[1].eq('undeterminded')).count() == 1)
```

but of course this isn't proper code.

I would need to have:

| RowID | FamilyID | Status | Gender | Gender_Inferred |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Fam_1 | head | undetermined | **male** |
| 2 | Fam_1 | wife | female | female |
| 3 | Fam_1 | child | undetermined | undetermined |
| 4 | Fam_1 | child | male | male |
| 5 |  | head | undetermined | undetermined |
| 6 | Fam_2 | head | female | female |
| 7 | Fam_2 | child | female | female |
| 8 | Fam_3 | head | undetermined | undetermined |
| 9 | Fam_3 | wife | female | female |
| 10 | Fam_3 | child | male | male |
| 11 | Fam_3 | head | undetermined | undetermined |

masking with groupby or updating with np.where (causing not matching length errors quite often) are not necessary mandatory, I would be happy with any working solution.

Thank you

Comment: I noticed a pattern in the input which you have shared. status == 'wife' appears after status == 'head'. is it the case always?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample input

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
[1,       "Fam_1",   "head",    "undetermined"],
[2,       "Fam_1",   "wife",    "female"],
[3,       "Fam_1",   "child",   "undetermined"],
[4,       "Fam_1",   "child",   "male"],
[5,       np.NaN,        "head",    "male"],
[6,       "Fam_2",   "head",    "female"],
[7,       "Fam_2",   "child",   "female"],
[8,       "Fam_3",   "head",    "undetermined"],
[9,       "Fam_3",   "wife",    "female"],
[10,      "Fam_3",   "child",   "male"],
[11,      "Fam_3",   "head",    "undetermined"],

], columns=["RowID", "FamilyID", "Status", "Gender"])
```

Marking FamilyID - nans as Single

```
df.FamilyID.replace(np.NaN, "Single", inplace=True)
```

Calculating number of heads in the family

```
heads_df = df.loc[df.Status == "head"].groupby("FamilyID")["Status"].count().reset_index(name="HeadCount")
```

Merging the information back to original df

```
df = df.merge(heads_df, on="FamilyID", how="left")
```

Adding a new column using shift

```
df["NextMember" ] = df.Status.shift(-1)
```

With all the information in place, run the query and assign

```
df.loc[
    (df.FamilyID != "Single")
    & (df.Status == "head")
    & (df.NextMember == "wife")
    & (df.Gender == "undetermined")
    & (df.HeadCount == 1)
    , "Gender"] = "male"
```

Drop newly created columns

```
df.drop(["HeadCount", "NextMember"], inplace=True, axis=1)
```

output

```
    RowID   FamilyID    Status  Gender
0   1   Fam_1   head    male
1   2   Fam_1   wife    female
2   3   Fam_1   child   undetermined
3   4   Fam_1   child   male
4   5   Single  head    male
5   6   Fam_2   head    female
6   7   Fam_2   child   female
7   8   Fam_3   head    undetermined
8   9   Fam_3   wife    female
9   10  Fam_3   child   male
10  11  Fam_3   head    undetermined
```

Note: From the sample input given above, I assumed that the status == wife will be followed by status == head. If my assumption is erroneous do lemme know. the solution will not work in such case.

Comment: Hi srinath, many thanks ! It so happens that on the impacted families, status "wife" indeed follows status "head", even if on the full file it is not always the case. Therefore your solution is working on my dataset. In the worst case, "NextMember" could be replaced by a "HasWife" helper (similar to heads_df), which would work as well.